# How can I manage Floating Action Buttons when I have a single Scaffold parent with many "pages" in the body (Flutter)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, state

perhaps a confusing question which I'll try to elaborate:

I am writing an app in Flutter and the app currently follows this basic structure:

```dart
// home.dart:
import 'dashboard.dart';
import 'profile.dart';
// so on, so forth...

Widget selectedPage = const DashboardPage();

Scaffold(
  body: selectedPage,
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Dashboard'),
          onTap: () => setState(() {
            selectedPage = const DashboardPage();
          }),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Profile'),
          onTap: () => setState(() {
            selectedPage = const ProfilePage();
          }),
        ),

        // so on, so forth...
      ]
    ),
  ),
)
```

This works well, however I would like to add Floating Action Buttons and have them do different things for each page (perform different functions, appear and disappear at different points). I was able to do this by just implementing a Stack and using the Position to place the Floating Action Buttons where they would normally sit within the Scaffold. Unfortunately, when I call ScaffoldMessenger.showSnackbar() the snackbar is displayed **over** the FABs and not above them as usual (with floating behaviour).

Is there some clever way for me to use the parent Scaffold FAB and allow it to respond to state changes in the children "pages"? Or is there some better way to do this?

Comment: simple answer. you can explore about `heroTag` property on FAB.

Comment: but i suggest for better code, you need to refactor the structur widget tree. you may try `IndexedStacked`

Comment: @pmatatias thanks for the suggestions! I'll check out the heroTag property. My only concerns with the IndexedStack widget is that I don't want to keep state for all of my widgets. I only want to respond to state changes of the currently displayed widget.